# iOS dialogs don't open in app, but in background

Tags: ios, cordova, dialog

After my cordova app is launched on iOS, the authorisation dialogs ("Do you want to grant access to your position?" etc.) do not appear in the app itself, but only open once the app is sent to the background and then reopened. This is obviously unreasonable for the user.

I'm having the same issue with the inAppBrowser, which only triggers once the app is reopened from the background.

Depending on the cordova CLI version I use to build, the results change for the better or worse. No error message anywhere.

Is there any plugin, setting or something else that could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
This happened because of a

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">
```

in the head of the programm. Removing this fixed the issue and everything works like it should.